# Does a set of continuous functions imply that a larger map is continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{f_\alpha: \alpha\in A\}$ be a set of continuous functions $f_\alpha: X\to Y$.
If $A, X, Y$ are all topological spaces, then is is true that $F: X\times A\to Y$ given by $F(x, a) = f_a(x)$ is continuous?

I'm also interested in a more specific application of this statement.
In my undergraduate topology class, the definition of a space $X$ being *path-connected* is that for any $x_1, x_2\in X$ there exists a continuous $h_{x_1, x_2}: [0, 1]\to X$.
If we define $H: X\times X\times [0, 1]\to X$ by $H(x_1, x_2, t) = h_{x_1, x_2}(t)$, then is $H$ necessarily continuous?

Comment: Is $F$ continuous? Not necessarily.

Comment: Can you explain why? A counter-example would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.  Consider the following family $f_t:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ for $t\in[0,1]$ defined by
$$f_t(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
x&:&0\leq t\leq\frac{1}{2}\\
-x&:&\frac{1}{2}<x<1.
\end{array}\right.$$
Then $f_t$ is continuous for all $t$, but the map $(x,t)\mapsto f_t(x)$ is not continuous on $\mathbb R\times[0,1]$.

The problem with the case you are concerned with is that path connectedness ensures the *existence* of a path, not that the path depend continuously on the points.  So you're question is not well-defined.  There are many choices for the path, hence many choices for the function $H$. and not all of them will be continuous.  For example, we can take $H:\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^2\times[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$ to be 
$$H(x_1,x_2,t)=(1-t)x_1+tx_2$$
 for $x_1\neq(1,0)$ and ,$x_2\neq(-1,0)$, and take 
$$H((1,0),(-1,0),t)=(\cos(\pi t),\sin(\pi t)),$$ 
and obtain a non-continuous map.  That's not to say you can't define a map $H:X\times X\times[0,1]\to X$ which will be continuous with $H(x_1,x_2,0)=x_1$ and $H(x_1,x_2,1)=x_2$ for all $x_1,x_2\in X$, but as the example suggests, it's certainly not guaranteed.

Comment: Ok, so now I see why the first statement is false. Is it possible however that the second statement is still true?

Comment: I edited to include some information about the second part of your question.